# Cypress. Автоматический редирект после Amazon Cognito авторизаци

Tags: javascript

На странице есть Amazon Cognito авторизация 
тоесть мы заходим на нужную страницу, и при первом заходе нас редиректает на стороннюю страницу и просят заполнить логин/пароль, после чего снова проходит редирект на нужную страницу

1. something.com
2. somethlogin.auth.eu-central-1.amazoncognito.com/login?client_id=4nafv8ipl1q5rttmrvv6oak5u7&redirect_uri=https%3A
3. something.com

Когда я написал по-старинке что то вроде такого

```
it('Open dev Carvago page', () => {
    cy.visit('/');

});

it('Fill auth popup', () => {
    cy.get("[id='signInFormUsername']")
        .eq(1)
        .type('Vladimir.Putin');
    cy.get("[id='signInFormPassword']")
        .eq(1)
        .type('gavzup-5Senfe-vabcopk');
    cy.get("[name='signInSubmitButton']")
        .eq(1)
        .click()
```

Cypress выдавал ошибку, и со страницы something.com на страницу авторизации редирект не проходил

Тогда я добавил строку

```
Cypress.config('chromeWebSecurity',false);
```

И у меня сработал редирект НА страницу авторизации и успешно заполнялись данные (1 -> 2)

НО со страницы авторизации на something.com обратно редирект не происходит (2 -> 3)

Как сделать, чтобы после заполнения формы проходил автоматический редирект со страницы 2 на 3 обратно ?

Answer (score 2):

У Cypress есть некоторые ограничение на смену глобальных URL'ов в одном тесте. Сталкивался с таким когда тестировал сайт, авторизация на котором происходила через сервисы Яндекса и там тоже были редиректы.

Помогло примерно следующее:

1. Изначально заходим не на Страницу 1, а на Страницу 2 или одну из страниц промежуточных редиректов. Тут придётся половить запросы.
2. Находим параметры, передающиеся в запросе.

Далее просто в cy.visit подставляем промежуточный URL с нужными параметрами.

Скорее всего пападёте на страницу авторизации (2) и сможете быстро её закончить.

Код будет примерно такой:

```
cy.visit('https://some-url.ru/authorize?parametr_1=some-value&paramert_2=some_valueq')
// В данном примере вместо нужного сайта перебрасывало на страницу авторизации с введённым логином

        cy.get('button').click() // Подтверждаем пользователя
        cy.get('.input-passwd"]').type('password')
        cy.get('button"]').click() // Подтверждаем пароль
        cy.get('button').eq(0).click() // Подтверждаем переход
```